# How to save text to file with the separated lines in Unity with c#

Tags: c#, android, io

When I try to save some text in Editor, I got **result1** when I want to save some text in the separated lines in my Android device, but I have result like this **result2**

```
result 1 is 
a
b
c
d

result 2 is
abcd
```

here's my code

```
public void savetofile()
{
    StreamWriter SW = new StreamWriter(" path to file "); 
    SW.WriteLine("a");
    SW.WriteLine("b");
    SW.WriteLine("c");
    SW.WriteLine("d");
}
```

According to docs of `WriteLine`

> Writes a string followed by a line terminator to the text string or stream.

each line should be printed with a newline at the end, but as showed in example this doesn't happen.  Can somebody tell me what's going wrong?

Comment: use SW.WriteLine("/r/n");

Answer (score 0):

You can use the control code "\n" for a new line.

```
public void savetofile()
{
    StreamWriter SW = new StreamWriter(" path to file "); 
    SW.WriteLine("a");
    SW.WriteLine("/n");
    SW.WriteLine("b");
    SW.WriteLine("/n");
    SW.WriteLine("c");
    SW.WriteLine("/n");
    SW.WriteLine("d");
}
```

Comment: If SW.WriteLine("/r/n"); doesn't work, try setting the line terminator string https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.textwriter.newline(v=vs.110).aspx or use Environment.NewLine

Answer (score 0):

I think you might want to try declaring a string than saving it if that would hep.

```
StreamWriter SW = new StreamWriter(" path to file "); 
string s = "a 
            b  
            c 
            d";   
SW.WriteLine(s);
```